# Neural Network checkpoints?

Tags: neural-network, checkpoint

I am new to Neural Network and I dont know what exactly to search on google for solution,here is my problem ,if you kindly please let me know what I am looking for,

So I am working on a project where,it will have many contributors over time,and each contributor will write a new line on excel file and then run the code to train dataset,
if want to ask is that ,is there a way to save a checkpoint so each time the code don't have to train the whole dataset and just continue to train the new entries instead of starting from zero.

Please let me know what exactly I should google.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Continual learning without forgetting"

Answer (score 1):

This is, as you guessed, extremely common and usually referred to as "fine-tuning". In your case, since the dataset barely changes between training runs, you can expect the model to be very similar, so you could initialize your weights to the weights of the previous best model and retrain for only a few epochs, likely with a small learning rate.

People usually do fine-tuning starting from a network trained on an entirely different dataset, so it's likely that you will find that use-case rather than yours, but it will work even better if you keep a very similar dataset.

Comment: hi,thanks ..with ur reply,i was able to reach to exact thing ,it is "Continual learning without forgetting"..thanks again